# HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: java, json, web-service, glassfish

Após tentar realizar uma chamada no WebService do Glasfish está ocorrendo o erro abaixo, estou tentando realizar uma chamada no Webservice Rest Json, na chamada rest de XML ele executa normalmente.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```java
package br.com.devmedia.ws.rest.example1;

import java.util.Random;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

@Path("ceprest")
public class CepRestWS {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public CepRestWS() {
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("getCep/{cep}")
    public Cep getCep(@PathParam("cep") String cep) {
        Cep toReturn = new Cep();
        toReturn.setCep(cep);
        toReturn.setBairro("Bairro " + new Random().nextInt());
        toReturn.setNumero(new Random().nextInt());
        toReturn.setRua("Rua que sempre " + new Random().nextInt());
        toReturn.setUf("PR");
        return toReturn;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tente copiar as JARs do jersey para a pasta WEB-INF\lib

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo baixei os JARs do Jersey, a apliquei diretamente na pasta lib do WEB-INF, após isso a IDE não deixou nem eu realizar o deploy da aplicação, retornando o seguinte erro: **cannot Deploy WebServerDevMediaEAR
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.json.bind.JsonbException. Please see server.log for more details.**

Comment: Complicou. Né? Acho que você tem problemas entre versões. Agora tem de ter calma, começar de novo, e ir passo a passo.